# Foursquare: Leveraging Search and Explore

Tags: foursquare

Is their a compromise between using the categoriesID of the search endpoint and the extended information given from the explore endpoint. I seem to be having issues querying specified venues queried using their categories ID and also having an extended list of information regarding the venue

Answer (score 0):

In order to associate venues you filtered with `categoryId` in `search` with their detail information (like tags, tips, photos, etc), I recommend you make a second call to the [`venue detail`](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) endpoint.

Yes, this means you would have to do one request to `venue detail` per resulting venue filtered in `search`.

Foursquare does not match these two together for you.

Comment: Ah yes I was hoping their was a way around it but that seems like the best solution. Thank you for the reconfirmation